# Google Identity ToolKit: createAuthUrl - Invalid Identifier

Tags: openid, google-openid, google-authentication

I'm working on implementing Google Identity Toolkit in my application.  Due to the unique customer requirement (FISMA), App Engine is an unacceptable platform.

I'd like the most seamless single sign on process with Google possible.  No buttons, no popups -- just a few redirects.  I'm thinking that the createAuthUrl method of the API is a good place to start.  However, I can't seem to get it to work.  I must be doing something wrong, but I'm totally stuck.

I've included a gist of some code I've tossed together:
https://gist.github.com/5bc9bfb03df34ca93cf3

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else who is out there searching, I created a code example that allows for Google-Identity-Toolkit handshakes in Python without any javascript/fluff.

https://github.com/richieforeman/google-identity-toolkit-python-silent